# Will flutter use cache for images?

Tags: flutter

For instance, there is a

```
const imgUrl = 'http://stackoverflow.com/logo.jpg'
```

On page 1 we display NetworkImage, then on page 2 we display the NetworkImage againe with the same image url. Will cached image be used? If not is it possible to use image from cache? And how to make it?

Comment: For reference: [the docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/cached-images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes by default this widget and Image.network() method will cache the image as flutter document described

> The image will be cached regardless of cache headers from the server.
>
> When a network image is used on the Web platform, the cacheWidth and
> cacheHeight parameters of the DecoderCallback are ignored as the Web
> engine delegates image decoding of network images to the Web, which
> does not support custom decode sizes.

but a better option would be using the [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) 2.3.3 plugin which flutter is recommending at [flutter_site/cookbook/working_with_cache_image](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/cached-images)  this plugin adds more caching functionality and a new widget for caching the image from network "CachedNetworkImage" widget is the same as Networkimage widget with some additional functionality for caching

here is the cached_network_image  pub page url : h[ttps://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)